# How fast should I refresh ads in my app?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I built a free app for android, and I'm using AdMob for my ads, does anyone have any recommendation's for how fast I should be refreshing ads? It's a scorekeeper so people are using it for 10-20 minutes at a time.

Comment: I wondered the same thing, so I set my refresh rate to as fast as possible. I don't see how it could hurt anyone but the admob servers (and maybe user data rates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maximum allowed frequency helps you to determine how much people are using the app and also increases the chances you'll present something somebody will want to click.